# Unknown "gradle failed" error while using buildozer

Tags: python, android, gradle, kivymd, buildozer

Creating an Android app in KivyMD with buildozer
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (In Windows 10 over WSL)
The problem: Running into an error with Gradle called (gradle failed)

I've been trying to create an Android app with KivyMD an buildozer via running the command: buildozer android debug.

The Python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

def one_and_zero(string: str):
    for i in string:
        if i == '1' or i == '0':
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

class Home(MDScreen):
    def get_data(self):
        x = str(self.ids.input.text)
        try:
            if x[2:].isnumeric() and x[:2] == "0b":
                self.ids.ans.text = str(eval(x))
            else:
                self.ids.ans.text = str(bin(int(x)))[2:]
        except:
                self.ids.ans.text = "Invaled value"

class Asciilator(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        return Builder.load_file('design.kv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Asciilator().run()
```

The "design.kv" file:

```
MDScreenManager:
    Home:

<Home>:
    name: "Home"

    MDLabel:
        text: ""
        id: ans
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 1,"center_y": .9}

    MDCard:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        size_hint: .95, .5

        FloatLayout:
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Calc"
                pos_hint: {"x": .8, "y": .45}
                on_release: root.get_data()
            MDTextField:
                id: input
                hint_text: "Insert the code"
                size_hint: None,None
                width: '200dp'
                pos_hint: {"x": .1, "y": .4}
                on_text_validate: root.get_data()
```

And here is the buildozer's log:

```
[INFO]:    COMMAND:                                                                                                     
cd /home/hashem207/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/asciilator && /home/hashem207/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/asciilator/gradlew clean assembleDebug                                                                                                                                                     
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/hashem207/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/asciilator/gradlew failed!                                                                                                                      
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.                                                   
Applying Java source code patches...                                                                                    
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
```

And finaly, The "buildozer.spec" file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Asciilator

# (str) Package name
package.name = asciilator

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = everysolver.org

# (str) Soucre code where the main.py live
source.dir = ./Project/

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py, png, kv, json

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, android_venv, .buildozer

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy==2.3.0,kivymd==1.1.1,pillow==10.2.0

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = ./Project/icon.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = ./Project/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.10.12

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.3.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
android.presplash_lottie = ./Project/start.json

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 34

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 26b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21
```